# How to contain an Entity inside another Entity when persisting EMF models, when such a relation is defined in meta-model?

Tags: eclipse, entity-framework, eclipse-emf-ecore, object-persistence, containment

I am trying to create a.XMI file for some Data I got from database, from an already defined metadata. The ecore has defined entities like :

Entity A

```
 |_Entity B

   |_Entity C

       |_Entity D.
```

But the model generated for me shows entities like :

Entity A

|_Entity B

|_Entity C

|_Entity D.

I am using resource.add function like :

```
resource.add(EntityA_object);
resource.add(EntityB_object);
resource.add(EntityC_object);
resource.add(EntityD_object);
```

I am new to EMF . So Any help would be appreciated :)